# How to resolve multicollinearity in linear regression using statsmodel?

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I got the following result after performing OLS:
[image]

I don't understand why I am getting the multicollinearity error. I referred to this[this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253334/how-to-solve-multicollinearity-problem-in-a-linear-regression) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/matrix-is-not-positive-definite-even-when-highly-correlated-variables-are-re/251050#251050). My Sources were one-hot encoded so I dropped one of them. Similarly, for Test_source. There are 3 related architectures - Bart, Peg and Human. So I've dropped the human column too. There are no other related columns so I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Sample data :

```
Sr.N| Num_of_texts| Length_of_Sentence| Cross_Domain| Repetition| Bart| Pegasus| Source_Xsum| Test_src_RCT| Test_src_Reddit| Test_src_SP| Test_src_Xsum|
    
1     11332.0        56.0                0.0          112.0        1    0         0             0              0                0           1
2     11332.0        16.0                0.0.         10.0         1    0         1             0              0                0           1
3     13368.0        40.0                0.0          78.0         0    1         0             0              0                0           0
4     13368.0        47.0                0.0          3.0          0    0         0             0              0                0           0
5     13368.0        63.0                0.0          8.0          0    0         0             0              0                0           0
6     6440.0         53.0                1.0          204.0        0    1         0             0              0                1           0
7     31091.0        17.0                1.0          24.0         0    1         1             0              1                0           0
8     6440.0         14.0                1.0          743.0        1    0         1             0              0                1           0
9     11332.0        12.0                0.0          2.0          0    0.        1             0              0                0           1
10    25146.0        26.0                1.0          141.0        0    1         0             0              1                0           0
11    13368.0        25.0                0.0          2.0          0    1         1             0              0                0           0
12    31091.0        46.0                1.0          13.0         0    1         1             0              1                0           0
13    11332.0        29.0                0.0          29.0         1    0         1             0              0                0           1
```

Comment: Did you check the VIF? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64415/71442

Comment: Among other things, you have some extreme outliers in your data.

Comment: I think you have a scaling problem. Based on the coefficient of your fitted results (e.g. **Num_of_texts=0.0853** and **Test_source_REDDIT=-1228.0164**), there is a large variation in your data value. for example **Test_source_REDDIT** data is in thousands while **Num_of_texts** is in 0.00 scale . Did you try to center your data? Giving sample data might help more.

Comment: @water77 I have added the sample data. I'm really confused about what is going on. Could you please help? The Num_of_texts is the number of test source texts I've used for that particular architecture. Are you suggesting I should normalize the column values?

Comment: @Kiera.K Please see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332428/regression-model-constant-causes-multicollinearity-warning-but-not-in-standardi). Yes, I am suggesting either centering ( X - mean(X)) or normalizing your data. But, please notice that centering or normalizing your data won't change your regression result.