# How to interpret the variables when we drop an independent variable to avoid collinearity in Regression?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, statsmodels, multicollinearity

I went through [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253334/how-to-solve-multicollinearity-problem-in-a-linear-regression) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51473/matrix-is-not-positive-definite-even-when-highly-correlated-variables-are-re/251050#251050). So whenever there are dummy variables which happen to be collinear, we need to drop one of them to avoid collinearity.
My confusion is how would I interpret the value of the other dummy variables with respect to the variable that I dropped?

For example, if I have 3 variables - Human, Bart and Pegasus, as binary variables. They represent how much repetition of words is there in each architecture. I dropped the human column and the values for the coefficient for Bart and Pegasus were :

[image]

Bart is -83.0908 and Pegasus is 76.5434. How do I interpret these in terms of the Human architecture? Please help!

Comment: Holding everything else constant, Bart decreases y by -83.09 compared to Human; while Pegasus increases y by 76.54.

Comment: @enke Thank you! So considering the amount of repetition by each architecture is my y, does it mean in comparison to "Humans", Bart has a lesser repetition of words than humans and Pegasus has more repetition of words than humans?

Comment: On average, yes.

Comment: @enke could you also pleaseee take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386496/how-to-resolve-multicollinearity-in-linear-regression-using-statsmodel
I'm really confused as to how to proceed there. Thank you!